# Centering composite content of a div

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a div that contains a bootstrap text element followed by font-awesome icons. Something like "login with" followed by the icons of various social networks. I am trying to get the whole block composed out of this text and the icons, vertically centered on the same line. What should be the best way? Currently using bootstrap and font-awesome icons. Typically we only center single elements which is easy, but here, the whole block should be centered at the middle of the page. What is the best way?

Comment: can you show a fiddle of what your problem is?

Comment: the problem is I am clueless about how to write html that center aligns, on one row, a sequence of elements. (e.g. in my case now, the sequence of elements is a text field followed by font-awesome icons). Centering an html element that contains them, will not get the correct visual effect as the html element is larger than it's content in some screen resolutions/sizes, so its alignment is not sufficient. I wonder if there's a way to accomplish the centering-alignment, with html, without going into javascript doing fancy size calculations and driving the dom. Maybe this clarifies a bit.

Comment: As @CoreyRowell suggests, create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or post your code in this post otherwise we're blind and it's much harder to help.